# calling image gallery from listview using intent

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-listview

i have an application which contains one activity and an adapter class for implementing listview.
Now in the listview when i click on the list view i need open the image gallery from device using intent.
but the problem is how to write the onActivityResult() as I'm calling the intent from adapter class. here is my code`

```
public class VehicleAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            holder.row = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lineItem);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        holder.image.setImageBitmap(getImageId().get(position));
        holder.txtName.setText(arr_calllog_name.get(position));

        holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                //arr_cars.remove(position);
                myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have deleted row No. "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the list views click handler in the activity and not in the adapter, store information in the tag of the item, then when an item is clicked in the list, you will be able to access the information and receive the onActivityResult event.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply can you provide some example code for that how to do it